# Jmeter - loop count does not work

Tags: jmeter

I have my TestPlan in Jmeter setup as below

```
Home HHTp Sampler

While loop
   Sampler for homepage/url
   csv file (2 urls)
```

After running for the Home page, I have a csv file with URLS (as of now 2) that i expect to be pulled out to run the next set of pages. I had set the loop count to 2, Number of Users = 5 and ramp uptime = 20 . But i saw that the execution happened for each user only once. It did not loop back the second time. How do i make it loop twice?

My csv file is set with config

```
recycle on EOF: False
stop thread on EOF: true
sharing mode: current thread
```

Comment: Did you get 5 samples, one for each user, or two samples, one for each URL?

Answer (score 2):

Set `recycle on EOF` to true, you want it to loop around

Set `stop thread on EOF` to false, you want it to loop around

The CSV Data source gives a new value each time the variable is accessed. If you want the first loop to use the same data for all users, you will need to copy the variable used in CSV config to another variable to be used by the other samples, so the CSV variable is only accessed once each loop.

In a beanshell sample at the start of the loop:

```
vars.put("USETHISVAR", vars.get("URLFROMCSV"));
```

Then in each sample that uses the URL, refer to ${USETHISVAR}

This will mean each user uses the same URL. The URL is updated each loop.

Comment: Should there be another CSV config element for this? I dont get it. If there is just my Home Page for 3 users and loop count 2, I get 6 HTTP requests. If my csv file has say just 1 URL, then I would expect 1 Home Page + 1 CSV url request for each user 2 times (6 requests totally). But i get only 3 requests for the 3 users. The looping doesnt happen.

Comment: What you expect is not how it works. You basically want to use the same URL for each user, and use the next URL next loop around, but there is no setting for that.  Each time you use the CSV variable, it is consumed and the next request will get the next URL. So you need to consume it once per loop. You could use a beanshell sampler to copy the variable to 2nd, then refer to the 2nd in each of your looping samples.